# Add columns to queryset and django-table2 table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-tables2

I have the following model and table;

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User")
    dob = models.DateField()

# tables.py
class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

I want to generate a SQL query to calculate the updated age of every Person on my MySQL DB on the fly, using 'dob' every time I retrieve objects, is it possible with django?

Moreover, if i can generate the sql query with aditional column "age" how can I add it to the table?
I am wondering if i should use django-table2 in this case.

**EDIT: I've solved doing this way.**

I've created a function on MYSQL for calculating age based on a arg type date.
Then I've use this function in an raw sql query in my view.

```
def get_persons(request):
    list_people = Person.objects.raw("SELECT *, age(date_birth) AS edad FROM mytable)
```

For adding this new age column to my table I've created a new Table class and added two columns "age" and "detail", like this:

```
class TablaBeneficiarios(tables.Table):
    age= tables.Column(orderable=True,verbose_name= "Age")
    detail= tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="/reports/beneficiario/{{record.id_beneficiario}}">Ver</a>',verbose_name="Acciones") #just a link column

    class Meta:
        model = FormularioA
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ("cod_pais", "num_familia", "num_miem_familia","fecha_ingreso_ret", "nombre", "prim_apellido",
                  "seg_apellido", "sexo", "etnia", "responsable", "age","detail")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # ...

    @property age(self):
        result_age = 'some queryset that return one column and one row' or datetime.date.today() - self.dob
        return result_age


class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    age = tables.Column('Custom name', order_by=('dob', ))  #  you cannot order by property, so put dob or orderable=False 

    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've solved yesterday, see the edit. Again thanks